# PHP Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: readdir

I had an old script (called Photopost Pro) installed on my server which was working fine. Today I had to move it to another folder on the same server, and I also changed its configuration to reflect the new location.

However I am now getting millions of these error messages:

PHP Warning:  readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /***/adm-inc.php on line 690

This error log keeps building in gigabytes and choking my server disk space. I am deleting it every few minutes and it keeps coming back.

This is the function at line 690 on that file:

```
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
```

And these are lines 684-710:

```
function dirsize($dir)
```

{

```
$dh = opendir($dir);
$size = 0;

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
{
   if ($file != "." and $file != "..")
   {
        $path = $dir."/".$file;

        if (is_dir($path))
        {
            $size += dirsize($path);
        }
        elseif (is_file($path))
        {
            $size += filesize($path);
        }
    }
}

closedir($dh);

return( $size );
```

}

It seems to me there must be some funny folder not being accessed or something similar? But why is this creating these millions of errors and how can I at least stop the errors? I don't care about the script actually working at this point. I even DELETED the adm-inc.php file and the error_log file still keeps getting the same error, even though that file is no longer there (!)

Comment: What I normally do is `if($dh = opendir($dir)) { while(...) { ... } }`. That way you only get the warning if the directory is absent. Another solution would be to create the directory _before_ it's accessed, but how easy that is depends on your code.

Answer (score 0):

After commenting that function out (or even removing the file) I thought it was strange it kept creating errors, so I restarted the httpd service and it seems to have stopped now finally. I don't know what caused it, but at least I've stopped the error_log problem.